# nginx setting up two subdomains with https and http not working

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have two sites to be used on my server load balancing them using nginx. First one www.something.club and other one is extras.something.club. The first one has https and http setup already, while extras.something.club I'm yet to set up https certs, so just need http.

The problem here is when I hit extras.something.club it opens same page as www.something.club and plus redirects to https://extras.something.club. Here the page should load extra.something.club owns page, and I do not nee https since certificate is of www, it starts giving me warning anyway. Below are the configurations I'm using.

**www.something.com has file at /etc/nginx/sites-available/web.conf and has symlink at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/web.conf. Below is config:**

```
upstream webapp {
   server 123.123.0.12:8080;
   server 123.234.0.18:8080;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name  www.something.club;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.something.club;

    ssl                       on;
    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.something.club/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.something.club/privkey.pem;

    # skipping some more ssl settings.

    access_log                /var/log/nginx/web.access.log;
    add_header                Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    location / {
      proxy_pass              http://webapp;
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

**extras.something.com has file at /etc/nginx/sites-available/extras.conf and has symlink at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/extras.conf**

```
upstream extraswebapp {
   server 123.123.0.12:8081;
   server 123.234.0.18:8081;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name extras.something.club;

   access_log                /var/log/nginx/web.access.log;
   add_header                Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

   location / {
     proxy_pass              http://extraswebapp;
     proxy_set_header        Host $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
}
```

I have verified this config with many sample available on various websites + documents. I was not able to locate anything wrong in this. Plus there nothing in code which redirects http to https for extra.something.club Plus if I access direct IPs with those port, it works perfectly fine & doesn't redirect to https as Nginx does.

Can somebody please help me to locate the problem?

Comment: You have defined `Strict-Transport-Security`. Your browser may be refusing to use `http`.

Comment: Yeah noticed that later after posting a question. I removed it from both the blocks. Restarted the server. Then still it would not go to port 80 of extras.something.club when I'm hitting it. I checked logs of nginx. it still goes to www.something.club

Comment: You need to wait 31536000 seconds, or reset the browser.